# PowerShell script wont scan for processes

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, process

I'm new to scripting any I am trying to make a script that reads PC list from a CSV file and check if a specific process is runnuing.

the following code is:

```
    Function LogWrite
    {
       Param ([string]$logstring)
       Add-content $Logfile -value $($(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss) + " - " + $logstring)
    }
    $LogFile = "Path\to\log.txt" # Location of local log file name
    $CsvLocation = "\\path\to\CSV\File\Table.csv" #Location of the CSV file
    $csvdata = Import-Csv $ipmCsvLocation

    foreach($pc in $csvdata) {
        $IcingaProc = "nscp.exe"
        $pcname = $pc.Name
        Write-Host $("Looking for process "+ $IcingaProc + " in " + $pcname + "...")
        $Processes = get-process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -Like "nscp*"}
        foreach($Proc in $Processes){
           if ($Proc.ProcessName -eq $IcingaProc){
             Write-Host "Program installed succefully"
             LogWrite ("Program installed succefully in "+$pcname)
             LogWrite `r`n
            }
            else{
             LogWrite ("Could not find any CINIGA process")
             LogWrite `r`n
            }
         }  
    }
```

```
This is the output I get:
PS User> powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass –Noprofile -file "Path\to\script.ps1"
Looking for process nscp.exe in PC1...
Looking for process nscp.exe in PC2...
Looking for process nscp.exe in PC3...
Looking for process nscp.exe in PC4...
```

it doesn't seems to enter the 2nd foreach loop..

Comment: Can you see the process in Task Manager?

Comment: Yes, for some computers

Comment: Your `Get-Process` cmdlet is not targetted at any specific computer. It's just searching on localhost. Use `Get-Process -ComputerName $pcname`

Comment: Are you an Admin?  You are seeing the process Task Manager because you are an Admin, but not running PS as Admin so you cannot kill the process.  Start PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: `$csvdata = Import-Csv $ipmCsvLocation` --> `$csvdata = Import-Csv $CsvLocation` and `get-process` --> `Get-Process -ComputerName $pcname`. Parameters to functions in PowerShell are sent without brackets and although in this case no error, better write `LogWrite "Program installed succefully in $pcname"`

Comment: @Scepticalist Its a bit strange.. now when he finds PCs that do have the process, it goes to the 'else' and writes that there is no process to be found

Comment: @jdweng I am running PS as admin

Comment: Write out all process names in foreach loop to see what code is finding : Write-Host "PC = " $pc.Name ", Process = " $Proc.ProcessName

Answer (score 0):

I was indeed pointing to localhost and changed to point to $pcName.
When i "turned" the if command with -ne instead of -eq it worked well!
Thank you for all your help !

```
Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)
   Add-content $Logfile -value $($(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HHmmss) + " - " + $logstring)
}
$LogFile = "Path\To\LogFIle.txt" # Location of local log file name
$CsvLocation = "\\Path\To\Referance\CSV\Table.csv"
$csvdata = Import-Csv $CsvLocation

foreach($pc in $csvdata) {
  $IcingaProc = "nscp"
  $pcname = $pc.Name
  Write-Host $("Looking for process "+ $IcingaProc + " in " + $pcname + "...")
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $pcname -Count 1 -Quiet) {
  $Processes = get-process -ComputerName $pcname | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -Like "ns*"}
  
     foreach($Proc in $Processes){   
      if ($Proc.ProcessName -ne $IcingaProc){
       Write-Host ("Could not find any process")
       }
       else{
        Write-Host "Program is installed succefully"
        LogWrite ("Program is installed on "+$pcname)
        } 
      }
   }
   else{
    Write-Host ("The PC is not reachable!")
   }  
}
```